# Insert auto closing quote in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to enable auto insert of closing single or double quote in visual studio 2017. So if I type " the editor should render "" and placing the cursor between the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following setting to True:

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Advanced -> Insert attribute value quotes
```